# Specifying methods to call on an unknown generic type

Tags: scala

Suppose I have code like the following:

```
abstract class GenericType[T]{
    val someSeq: Seq[T]

    def list() = for(item <- someSeq) println(item)
}

class ConcreteType extends GenericType[Int] {
    val someSeq = Seq(1, 2, 3)
}

object MyApp {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val ct = new ConcreteType
        ct.list()
    }
}
```

That simply prints out 1 2 3 (on separate lines). But suppose that I wanted to create an instance of generic type that calls some method of `T`, instead. For example, suppose I wanted to call an integer's `max` method. How would I specify the method to call?

I presume that somehow I could create a value in the abstract class that contains the method to call on each `item` and specify that method in the concrete class.

So in other words, I want to end up with something like:

```
abstract class GenericType[T]{
    val someSeq: Seq[T]
    val methodToCall: ???

    def list() = for(item <- someSeq) println(item.methodToCall)
}

class ConcreteType extends GenericType[SomeType] {
    val someSeq = Seq(1, 2, 3)
    val methodToCall = ???.max(_, 2)
}
```

And would expect `main` to then print out 2 2 3 (ie, the result of `for(item <- someSeq) println(item.max(_, 2))`).

Comment: Of course, one solution would be to use reflection and specify string names of methods to call, but this has performance issues that I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this. You can only return values, and methods are not values. You can, however, take a function and pass a lambda or convert the method to a function through η-expansion.

```
abstract class GenericType[T] {
  def someSeq: Seq[T]

  type MapResult
  def map: T => MapResult

  def list() = someSeq.foreach(map andThen println)
}

class ConcreteType extends GenericType[Int] {
  override val someSeq = Seq(1, 2, 3)

  override type MapResult = Int
  override val map = 2.max(_)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would personally try to use type classes. Here is example:

```
  trait MethodToCall[T, R] {
    def invoke(obj: T): R
  }

  implicit object IntToCall extends MethodToCall[Int, Int] {
    override def invoke(obj: Int): Int = obj.max(2)
  }

  abstract class GenericType[T]{
    def someSeq: Seq[T]

    def list[R](implicit mtc: MethodToCall[T, R]) =
      for(item <- someSeq) println(mtc.invoke(item))
  }

  class ConcreteType extends GenericType[Int] {
    val someSeq = Seq(1, 2, 3)
  }

  new ConcreteType().list[Int]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify return type of 'mtehodToCall', I use T for example

```
  abstract class GenericType[T]{
    def someSeq: Seq[T]
    def methodToCall: T => T

    def list() = for(item <- someSeq) println(methodToCall(item))
  }

  class ConcreteType extends GenericType[Int] {
    val someSeq = Seq(1, 2, 3)
    val methodToCall: Int => Int = math.max(_, 2)
  }

  new ConcreteType().list()
```

Comment: `max` above was just an example. I'm actually trying to call some method of `T`'s (which I already know the type signature of).